# How to position a popup div based on the position of where the cursor clicks

Tags: jquery

I am trying to position a popup div below:

```
<div style="display:none;height:200px;width:200px;border:3px solid green;" id="popup">Hi</div>
```

based on the clicking of another div.

I am running this on document .ready

```
$('div#d').bind('click', function (event) {
var offset = $(this).offset();
$('#popup').css('left',offset.left);    
$('#popup').css('top',offset.top);
$('#popup').css('display','inline');        
});
```

but the above will not even display the div

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem lie in the fact that offset() do not return the correct mouse position, try event.pageX and event.pageY instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#d').bind('click', function (event) {
    $('#popup').css('left',event.pageX);      // <<< use pageX and pageY
    $('#popup').css('top',event.pageY);
    $('#popup').css('display','inline');     
    $("#popup").css("position", "absolute");  // <<< also make it absolute!
    });
});
```

See [here](http://postimage.org/image/k00jvu4jn/).

Comment: If the containing element is position:absolute or relative, positioning the popup absolutely causes it to appear relative to the container, not the page.

Comment: For easy reference and improvements, here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hwsamuel/fsp5pgqw/

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `position: absolute` to your div. Make sure it isn't located within another div that has relative positioning.

```
<div style="position: absolute; display:none;height:200px;width:200px;border:3px solid green;" id="popup">Hi</div>
```

Top and left only work for elements with `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` positioning.

Comment: that is working well for displaying the div,thank you, but it is not positioning the div where the cursor clicked

Comment: Did you make sure that div isn't inside something else that has relative positioning? Try making it the very first or very last item in your body.